# Is satire on the Quran allowed?

Tags: fatwa, judaism, jews, torah

I'm doing some research about freedom of speech in Islam, and I am wondering if there are instances where satire on Islam is permitted.

One of my points of reference is in Judaism, where there exists a concept called "[Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah)" which is when Jews traditionally draw silly and humorous conclusions and lessons from stories in the Torah that are clearly not the real lesson or may not even make much sense in reality.

Do we have a similar allowance for such a practice in Islam?

Comment: For anyone interested, here's a link to Purim Torah on Judaism.SE: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest

Answer (score 2):

#### NO

Good that you asked before. Any ways, mocking the Qur'anic verses by non believers is expected,

> But you wonder, while they mock, And when they are reminded, they remember not. And when they see a sign, they ridicule And say, "This is not but obvious magic...." (Qur'an 37:12-15)

But why would you ever want to create disparities and conflicts and more rage?

Well among the Muslims, Qur'an is the highest valued object material than anything else. So, such ill conduct(deducing false beliefs) is by no means expected within Islam.

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: Is there not even room for a little bit of Quran humor, like the Jews do on Purim with their holy book?